# How to work with files having a .wdb extension (Microsoft Works database) in python?

Tags: python

I have got a few files with a .wdb extension (Microsoft Works datatabse). I would like to process these and see what information they have.

Could you please suggest ways that I might accomplish this?

Comment: Try something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:JesseW/wdb_format, but the link to the python script is broken.  So I"m guessing you'd have to RE the .wdb format

Comment: OK. let me try and see.